# DQN - Cannot solve Cartpole-v1 - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've been trying to solve CartPole-V1 by achieving average reward of 475 in 100 consecutive steps.

That's the algorithm I need to run: 
[image]

I've tried many architectures of DQN with Fixed Q values. What am I doing wrong?

Those are my hyper parameters:

```
    TOTAL_EPISODES = 5000
    T = 500
    LR = 0.01
    GAMMA = 0.95
    MIN_EPSILON = 0.01
    EPSILON_DECAY_RATE = 0.9995
    epsilon = 1.0  # moving epsilon

    state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    action_size = env.action_space.n
    batch_size = 64
    C = 8
    reward_discount = 10
    deque_size = 2000
    experience_replay = deque(maxlen=deque_size)
```

I've tried playing with LR in [0.01, 0.02, 0.001], reducting epsilon decay rate, batch_size = 32, C = 4, ...

The implementation is the same as in the picture, I will put the non trivial parts:

```
def train_on_batch(batch_size, memory, gamma, model, ddqn_target_model, losses):
    minibatch = random.sample(memory, batch_size)
    states = np.zeros((batch_size, 4))
    targets = np.zeros((batch_size, 2))

    for index, (state, action, reward, next_state, done) in enumerate(minibatch):
        states[index] = state.reshape(1, 4)
        model_target = model.predict(state.reshape(1, 4))
        target_pred = ddqn_target_model.predict(next_state.reshape(1, 4))
        if done:
            target = reward
        else:
            target = reward + gamma * (np.amax(target_pred))

        model_target[0][action] = target
        targets[index] = model_target[0]
    history = model.fit(states, targets, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    losses.append(history.history['loss'][0])


def build_model(state_size, action_size, learning_rate, layers_num=3):
    model = Sequential()
    if layers_num == 3:
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    else:
        model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(action_size, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate))

    return model

def sample_action(model, state, epsilon):
    if random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:
        action = env.action_space.sample()
    else:
        action_pred = model.predict(state)
        action = np.argmax(action_pred[0])

    return action
```

At first I do `ddqn_target_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())` and inside the episode iteration I do `if episode % C == 0:
            ddqn_target_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())`

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The problem was that I was updating the target model weights every C episodes instead of every C steps.